# Can I have a YouTube account while having nothing to do with Google Plus?

Tags: youtube, google-plus, privacy, google-account, username

[This page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3479363) describes three options for what name will be displayed for you on YouTube, but they all seem to involve associating with Google Plus in some way.  If you want your Google name used in both Google apps and YouTube, a Google Plus profile will be created for you.  If you want your YouTube username used in both, a Google Plus Profile will also be created for you.  And if you want your Google name in Google products and your YouTube username on YouTube (which is what I'd ideally want), a Google Plus *page* will be created for you.

So my question is, are there any options for someone who wants to keep their YouTube account but have nothing to do with Google Plus?  I'd prefer if neither Google Plus pages nor Google Plus profiles were created for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the title it is stated that this is **optional for channels**.

As outlined in the first paragraph this is not required. Just something Channels may want to do. Weather you'll be able to keep your accounts separated is in the hands of Google